# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\partial_1 \partial_2f$ exists everywhere. Does it follows that $\partial_1f $ exists?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\partial_1 \partial_2f$ exists everywhere. Does it follows that $\partial_1f$ exists?

I guess this not true, but I can't find a proper example.

Answer (score 3):

Take
$$
f(x,y) = g(x)
$$
where $g$ is any one-variable function that is nowhere differentiable, e.g. $g(x) = 1$ if $x$ if $x$ is rational $g(x) = 0$ if $x$ is irrational.

Comment: @mrf...is $\partial_1 \partial_2f$  exists your example is difficult to understand me..sorry

Comment: @mrf...can you explain bit more

Comment: In the example, $\partial_2 f = 0$ everywhere.